# How can I make a NetBeans search for HTML that includes odd white space?

Tags: search, regex, netbeans

For example, for code with lots of snippets like this:

```
<section>
    <p><b>test</b></p>
</section>
```

I want to be able to search for:

```
<section>
    <p><b>
```

So that I can replace it with

```
<section>
    <h2>
```

But not replace other `<p><b>` that do not have a section tag immediately before it.

So, I can't search for `<p><b>` but NetBeans won't allow me to paste in selections with white space. So, I'm assuming I need to make a regex search for something like:

```
<section>(any-white-space)<p><b>
```

But I'm not sure quite how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you're asking how to build a regex?  There's TONS of info out there on doing that (for example: http://www.regular-expressions.info/).  What have you tried already?  Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: @techie007 I tried about (literally) 20 different combinations of searching for exact html tags with variable whitespace in-between and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I'm curious as to how you tried to match a variable whitespace. Could you perhaps give some of the patterns you tried?

Comment: I mean which Regex patterns have you tried?  `\s` should cover spaces, tabs and newlines, or a group like `[\n\r\t ]` (if `\s` isn't supported in the Regex version you're using), for example.

Comment: I tried #^<section>\s<p><b>#, ^<section>\s<p><b>, <section>\s<p><b>, #^<section>\s*<p><b>#, and about 20 others. I guess not exactly sure how neatbeans regex search works.

Comment: Like I said, not all versions of Regex support `\s`, try `<section>[\n\r\t ]<p><b>`.

Comment: I dont think it's having a problem with \s, I think its having a hard time matching the tags plus the \s. I can run \s alone and finds whiteapce. I'm posting this on superuser because I'm hoping to find someone with experience white regex on netbeans, not downvotes from people who don't know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this in jEdit (which is also written in Java like Netbeans but I don't have access to Netbeans at the moment). Try this for the regex pattern:

```
(?<=<section>)(\s*)<p><b>([^<]+)</b></p>
```

with this used as the replacement:

```
$1<h2>$2</h2>
```

The regex pattern says "match a sequence which is preceded by `<section>` and starts off with any amount of whitespace (which is stored as capture group 1) and then contains `<p><b>` followed by at least one character which is not `<` (and store these characters as capture group 2) and ends with `</b></p>`".

The replacement pattern just says "start off with the whitespace from capture group 1, then output `<h2>` then the characters from capture group 2 which were found inside the `<b>` element, then output `</h2>`." Capturing and outputting the whitespace means that your new h2 element will begin with the same newlines and tabs as the p element, so any pretty formatting won't be ruined by the change.

Just bear in mind that regex has no way of knowing where it is relative to the DOM structure so it can't know whether it's correct to use h1, h2, h3, h4, and so on. But if you only ever need `<h2>` then give this a try.

(Actually, if you're using HTML5 then you can start each new section element with an `<h1>` element, or any other starting number in fact, and a compliant browser is required to handle the header levels automatically.)